# Error: constructor annot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

При компиляции появляется ошибка:

```
error: constructor AnimalState in class AnimalState cannot be applied to 
given types;
return new AnimalState( hoursSinceLastMeal, energyPercent, age, 
isProliferating, isFeedingNewborns, weight );
```

Подскажите пожалуйста из за чего эта ошибка?

Класс Animal

```
import java.time.Duration;

public  class Animal
{
    public static  int hoursSinceLastMeal = 3;
    public static  int energyPercent = 87;
    public static  int age = 7; 
    public static  boolean isProliferating = false;
    public static  boolean isFeedingNewborns = true;
    public static  int weight = 3;

    public int getId() {
    return hashCode();
    }

    public static AnimalState state() {
    return new AnimalState( hoursSinceLastMeal, energyPercent, age,     
    isProliferating, isFeedingNewborns, weight );
    }
}
```

Класс AnimalState

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class AnimalState extends Animal {

int hoursSinceLastMeal;
int energyPercent; 
int age; 
boolean isProliferating; 
boolean isFeedingNewborns;
int weight;

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s", hoursSinceLastMeal, energyPercent, age, isProliferating, isFeedingNewborns, weight);
}
```

Comment: Ну, надо конструктор написать, сейчас конструктора нет и по умолчанию генерируется пустой конструктор (без аргументов)

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но разве state() не выполняет функции конструктора?

Comment: Нет, state это обычный метод в классе Animal, который возвращает объект класса AnimalState. Конструктор класса AnimalState надо объявлять внутри класса AnimalState, примерно так: `public AnimalState(int param1, int param2, ...) { ... }`. Не очень понятно правда зачем вам здесь два класса...